# non-linear optimization on the GPU (CUDA) without data transfer latency

Tags: cuda, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to perform a non-linear optimization problem entirely on the GPU. Computation of the objective function and data transfer from the GPU to CPU are the bottlenecks. To solve this, I want to

1. heavily parallelize computation of the objective and
2. perform the entire optimization on the GPU.

More specifically, the problem is as follows in pseudo-code:

```
x = x0  // initial guess of the vector of unknowns, typically of size ~10,000
for iteration = 1 : max_iter
      D = compute_search_direction(x)
      alpha = compute_step_along_direction(x)
      x = x   +   D * alpha  // update
end for loop
```

The functions `compute_search_direction(x)` and `compute_step_along_direction(x)` both call the objective function `f0(x)` dozens of times per iteration. The objective function is a complicated CUDA kernel, basically it is a forward Bloch simulation (=the set of equations that describes the dynamics of nuclear spins in a magnetic field). The output of `f0(x)` are F (value of the objective function, scalar) and DF (Jacobian, or vector of first derivatives, with same size as x, i.e. ~10,000). On the GPU, `f0(x)` is really fast but transfer of x from the CPU to the GPU and then transfer back of F and DF from the GPU to the CPU takes a while (~1 second total). Because the function is called dozens of time per iteration, this leads to a pretty slow overall optimization.

Ideally, I would want to have the entire pseudo code above on the GPU. The only solution I can think of now is recursive kernels. The pseudo code above would be the "outer kernel", launched with a number of threads = 1 and a number of blocks = 1 (i.e., this kernel is not really parallel...). This kernel would then call the objective function (i.e., the "inner kernel", this one massively parallel) every time it needs to evaluate the objective function and the vector of first derivatives. Since kernel launches are asynchronous, I can force the GPU to wait until the `f0` inner kernel is fully evaluated to move to the next instruction of the outer kernel (using a synchronization point).

In a sense, this is really the same as regular CUDA programming where the CPU controls kernel launches for evaluation of the objective function `f0`, except the CPU is replaced by an outer kernel that is not parallelzied (1 thread, 1 block). However, since everything is on the GPU, there is no data transfer latency anymore.

I am testing the idea now on a simple example to test feasibility. However, this seems quite cumbersome... My questions are:

1. Does this make any sense to anyone else?
2. Is there a more direct way to achieve the same result without the added complexity of nested kernels?

Comment: The other choice that comes to mind is a cooperative launch with grid-wide sync.

Comment: My answer would Q1. be no. You could probably write the outer loop, which is serial, in python with each of the calculations done on the GPU and get the same performance,

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are mixing up "reducing memory transfer between GPU and CPU", and "having the entire code run on device (aka. on gpu)".

In order to reduce memory transfers, you **do not need** to have the entire code run on GPU.

You can copy your data to the GPU once, and then switch back and forth between GPU code and CPU code. As long as you don't try to access any GPU memory from your CPU code (and vice-versa), you should be fine.

Here's a pseudo-code of a correct approach for what you want to do.

```
// CPU code
cudaMalloc(&x,...) //allocate memory for x on GPU
cudaMemCpy(x, x0, size, cudaMemCpyHostToDevice); //Copy x0 to the freshly allocated array 
cudaMalloc(&D, ....)    //allocate D and alpha before the loop
cudaMalloc(&alpha, ....)
for iteration = 1 : max_iter
      compute_search_direction<<<...>>>(x, D) //Call a kernel that does the computation and stores the result in D
      compute_step_along_direction<<<....>>>(x, alpha)
      combine_result<<<...>>>(x, D, alpha)  // x   +   D * alpha
end for loop
//Eventually copy x on CPU, if need be
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The only way the kernels would have the opportunity to run concurrently is if they were placed in separate streams.  If they are all issued into the same stream (or all issued into the default stream) there is no possibility for them to run concurrently.

Comment: Right! I didn't know that. I guess I've been placing way too many synchronizers in my codes. Thanks, I'm gonna edit my answer

Comment: yes, that's basically what I mentioned in my post: Nested kernels... Since the kernels `compute_search_direction<<<...>>>` and `compute_step_along_direction<<<....>>>` call each many times the objective function kernel `f0<<<...>>>`. Which is fine (dynamic parallelism), I was just wondering if there is another solution...

Comment: @Bastien I'll try to explain differently. First thing I should mention: Nested kernel are not allowed in Cuda, so the implementation you described cannot possibly compile. Cf.: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/455713/cuda-programming-and-performance/nesting-kernels-can-i-do-this-in-cuda-/

Comment: You said: "The pseudo code above would be the "outer kernel", launched with a number of threads = 1 and a number of blocks = 1 (i.e., this kernel is not really parallel...)". It will not compile since nested kernels are not allowed, so you should definitely not do that. The pseudo-code can and should be run on CPU, without losing optimality

Comment: Last thing, since nested kernels are not allowed, f0 is not a kernel, but a __device__ function

Comment: I don't know what "nested kernels are not allowed" means.  But without getting into the nitty-gritty of this answer, I think it is saying the same thing as the comment from talonmies.  It should not be necessary to use dynamic parallelism to get nearly all the benefit you are likely to see here.  The largest benefit will come from getting all your data on the GPU, then calling the kernels as often as is needed.  The loop you have shown in your question is something like the loop that would be used in a conjugate gradient descent, and there is a CUDA sample code for that.